# How to exclude a cell from a range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Help me find a solution, please. There is a column in a table with data. Task: when entering data into any cell of this column, check whether the same value already exists in other cells of this column and notify the user (check for duplicates). I know how to loop through a column, but I don’t know how to make it not take the current cell into account when checking. Thank you.
My solution was obviously wrong.

```
function DoublesCheck(){

let sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
let sourse = sh.getSheetByName("Склад");
let data = sourse.getActiveCell().getValue();
let dataArr = sourse.getRange("A:A").getValues();
let clearArr = dataArr.map(function(r){return r[0];})
let a = clearArr.indexOf(data);

  for ( let i = 0; i<dataArr.length; i++) {
    if (i==a)
    continue;
    if ([dataArr.indexOf(data)] !== -1) 
      Logger.log("already exist")
      break 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `onEdit()` I check to make sure the value has not already occured in the column.  For my testing I use Sheet1 and column A.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if( e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Sheet1" ) {  // limit input to Sheet1
    if( e.range.getColumn() === 1 ) { // limit input to column A
      let sheet = e.range.getSheet();
      let values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
      let row = e.range.getRow()-1; // the row your editing
      let found = -1;
      values.some( (value,index) => {
          if( index !== row ) {
            if( value[0] == e.value ) { // have to use == here
              found = index;
              return true;
            }
          }
          return false;
        }
      );
      if( found < 0 ) return;
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Value ["+e.value+"] already input!")
      e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);
    }
  }
}
```

Reference

- [onEdit() trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)
- [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [Array.some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Checking and Warning for duplicates and returning to old value if found

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if (e.range.columnStart > 1 || sh.getName() != "Sheet2") return;
  //e.source.toast("Gate1");
  let v = sh.getActiveCell().getValue();
  let vs = sh.getRange("A1:A" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  let o = vs.reduce((a, cv, i) => {
    if (cv == v && (e.range.rowStart - 1) != i) { a.push(i + 1); } return a;
  }, []);
  if (o.length) {
    e.source.toast(`The value ${v} already exists at row ${o[0]}`);
    e.range.setValue(e.oldValue);//resets to oldvalue
  };
}
```

- [Array.methods()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. Probably you can to highlight the duplicates with 'Conditional forman rules' with a formula like this:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$100,$A1)>1
```

[image]

The main advantage of formulas — they usually work much faster than a script driven by a trigger.

More tricks are here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/google-sheets-highlight-duplicates/